# Zend framework where to declare the values that appear in all pages

Tags: zend-framework

I have a log in form that appears at the top of the page. I should appear only if the user is not logged in in all pages. Where should i declare the class that generates login form so that i can use it in my layout.
i tried on my bootstrap class

```
protected function _initView(){
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($view->baseUrl('/css/default.css'));
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();       
if(!$auth->hasIdentity()) { 
        $login = new Application_Form_User();
        $view->login = $login;
    }
```

}
didn't work either. I Also tried

```
protected function _initView(){
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('http://localhost/backend/public/css/default.css');
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();       
    if(!$auth->hasIdentity()) { 
            $login = new Application_Form_User();
            $view->login = $login;
}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a view helper like so:

```
class Application_View_Helper_LoginForm
{
    public function loginForm()
    {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

        if(!$auth->hasIdentity())
        {
            $login = new Application_Form_User();
            return $login;
        }
    }
}
```

You must also register the view helper path in your Bootstrap. Parameter one is the path and parameter two is the prefix of the class name.

```
protected function _initViewHelpers()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');

    $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/helpers/', 'Application_View_Helper');
}
```

Then to display the form, add the following code in your layout:

```
<?php echo $this->loginForm(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting ...Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'LoginForm' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/var/www/backend/application/views/helpers/' ........ And i had named the file loginform.php in /application/views/helpers

Answer (score 1):

Use a view helper to display the form / "logged in" text.

You can use a specific controller action to handle the form or use a controller action helper to handle the login form submission on any page.

Answer (score 0):

Use a front controller plugin for that.
See http://devzone.zend.com/article/3372